# How to Compare Datatables

Tags: c#, datagridview

### Background

I have a set of numbers between 1000-9999 split between two data tables both with same the Schema. One data table's schema is then cloned, and then filled with the rows from both of the original tables. This third new data table is then displayed in a datagridview.

### Question

How could I then highlight the rows in the datagridview that contain rows from the first data table?

### Code

```
 private void combineTables()
        {
            bothIdsTbl = UsedIdsTbl.Clone();
            dataGridView3.DataSource = bothIdsTbl;


            for (int i = 0; i <= UnUsedIdsTbl.Rows.Count - 1; ++i)
            {
                bothIdsTbl.ImportRow(UnUsedIdsTbl.Rows[i]);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= UsedIdsTbl.Rows.Count - 1; ++i)
            {

                bothIdsTbl.ImportRow(UsedIdsTbl.Rows[i]);
            }

           dataGridView3.Sort(this.dataGridView3.Columns["stationid"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);


         }
```

Comment: You may not need to import the data to a third table unless you have some serious requirement. Create a view by joining two tables or join the two tables in your query.

Comment: You can create views on Datatables in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be the following:

- Add a "flag" column to 3rd table before filling it,
- Put in that column a value indicating wheteher the row was imported or not from 1st table.
- Use the CellFormatting event of the DataGridView to change
  cells backcolor according to the flag column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command named merge to combine the two datatables.

If this data came from a database you may consider a union query or any other option to combine the data or obtain all the data in one call.

Comment: Thats what I've gone with. However only one table came from a db, the other create programatically, so not able to union.